# Selecting nodes that have an attribute with spaces using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: .net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to select all the `li` elements in from the following:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li class="third left">
         ...
        </li>
        <li class="third left">
         ...
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm using the following XPath query but this returns nothing.

```
 Dim result As HtmlNodeCollection = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[@class='third left']")
```

Are attributes with spaces treated differently? Using [this](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm) tool the XPath works correctly.

Comment: Your XPATH is 100% correct. It works fine with me. What Html Agility Pack Version do you use? I'm using 1.3.0.0.

Comment: I'm using 1.4.0, the latest version as far as I'm aware. I'll try using an older version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SimonMourier said, your XPath is correct. I suggest you doing the following:

- Posting the entire HTML source and telling us if you're loading it from a file or directly from the web
- Writing in a text file the content of `htmlDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml` into a text file. If you're loading the HTML from the web, maybe you're getting a *404* (*Not Found*) or something ;)

Comment: Accepting this as the answer. The XPath was correct and your advice let determine that the site was rejecting requests on non-standard user agents.

Comment: @Soliah Alright. I guess you solved it (changing the user-agent). If not let us know and we will help you :)